# View throws error due to asynchronous object loading

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an Ionic 2 app where one component retrieves a `client` from a service and provides it as an input on it's child component.  The child component keeps throwing an error because when it's initialized, `client` is still undefined.

**Parent**

```js
@Component({
  template: `
        <client-generic [client]="client"></client-generic>
  `,
})

export class TabComponent {
    client:any;
    client_id:any;
    token:any;
    current_user:any;
    constructor(private params: NavParams, private clientService: ClientService) {
        this.client_id = params.get("client_id")
        this.current_user = params.get("current_user")
        this.token = this.current_user.auth_token

        this.clientService.newGetClient(this.client_id, this.token).subscribe(client => { 
        this.client = client; 

      // Logs properly
      console.log(this.client);
    });
  }
}
```

**Child**

```js
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'client-generic.html',
  selector: 'client-generic'
})

export class ClientGenericPage {
  @Input() client: any;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
    public modalController: ModalController, private clientService: ClientService) {

    // Logs undefined
    console.log("Client", this.client)
  }
}

ngOnInit() {
    // also logs undefined
    console.log(this.client);
}
```

What can I do to ensure that `client` is defined in the child?

Comment: `<client-generic *ngIf="client" [client]="client"></client-generic>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following changes in your parent component

```
@Component({
  template: `
        <client-generic [client]="client" *ngIf="!isLoading"></client-generic>
  `,
})

export class TabComponent {
    client:any;
    client_id:any;
    token:any;
    current_user:any;
    isLoading: boolean = true;
    constructor(private params: NavParams, private clientService: ClientService) {
        this.client_id = params.get("client_id")
        this.current_user = params.get("current_user")
        this.token = this.current_user.auth_token

        this.clientService.newGetClient(this.client_id, this.token).subscribe(client => { 
        this.client = client; 
        this.isLoading = false;
      // Logs properly
      console.log(this.client);
    });
  }
}
```

You can read this [3 Ways to Pass Async Data to Angular 2+ Child Components](https://scotch.io/tutorials/3-ways-to-pass-async-data-to-angular-2-child-components) to know more about the problem.